# why bandpass filtering (butterworth) centers the signal

Tags: filters, bandpass

I run bandpass filtering via the `butter()` in matlab to apply butterworth bandpass filtering to find out the signals are centered at zero after the filter. Would this always happen for any kind of low/high-pass filtering and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

High pass filtering means that low-frequencies, including DC, are removed. So if your signal has a DC offset (is not zero mean), then this will be removed by a highpass filter or a bandpass filter that does not include 0 in the passband.